# SCNPhysicsBody poor performance

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm developing an Augmented Reality app which uses a mesh for physics and occlusion. Mesh is an irregularly shaped geometry which consists of many vertices all around the camera.

To have a correct physics shape for the mesh, I have to add `SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron` option when creating `SCNPhysicsShape`, other options are drawing bounding box around the shape which makes physics impossible, because camera is positioned inside the mesh.

This works fine, but the performance is awful. Is there anything that can be done to increase the efficiency of this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier for a physics engine to test for collisions against multiple simple (convex) geometries than against a single, large, complex, concave geometry.

Looking at a simpler form of your problem: If you want to model a typical room for collision detection, you don't create a geometry with a concave cuboid shape in the middle, you create four walls, a floor and a ceiling, using `SCNPlane` or `SCNBox` for each.

For a more complex set of physics-interactive surfaces around the camera, just scale up that idea. Build up an arrangement of impostor shapes that together roughly matches your visual geometry — ideally using `SCNBox`, `SCNSphere`, or other primitive geometries — then use [`init(node:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsshape/1508889-init) to make that into a physics shape.

Comment: Thanks, but mesh geometry is built live based on depth data retrieved from camera, I do not place these collision geometries manually. Also, the precision of geometry is quite important, replacing parts with regularly shaped geometries will most definitely lose that.

Comment: What’s the resolution of your depth map? (If we’re talking live depth maps from TrueDepth camera, it’s much less than that of the screen, or of the color camera image.) I’d bet you could see a performance improvement without much accuracy tradeoff from approximating each depth map pixel as a sphere. And you could try downsampling the depth map and using larger spheres to tune for a performance/accuracy sweet spot.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this